# Decompress gzip file to specific directory

Tags: compression, gzip

What is the gzip equivalent of the following command:

```
tar xvzf /usr/local/file/file/file.tar.gz -C /usr/local/extract_here
```

I am trying

```
gzip -d /usr/local/file/file/file.tar.gz -C /usr/local/extract_here
```

but it does not work, how do I do that with gzip?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Given the fact that you have a .tar.gz file, the first way you tried, with the -C option, will work just fine:

`tar xvzf /dir/to/file.tar.gz -C /dir/to/output/`

`tar` calls gzip to decompress, and then extracts the files from the tar stream.  `gzip` can only decompress, so `gunzip file.tar.gz` would simply leave with the decompressed `file.tar`, on which you would then need to `tar xvf file.tar`.  The `z` option of `tar` is simply a shortcut to do the decompression with gzip along with extracting the files.

If you want to just decompress a .gz file (as opposed to extracting a .tar.gz file) to a different directory, simply pipe there.  E.g. `gzip -dc < file.gz > /somewhere/file`.

Comment: If you want to move the question to a different sx platform I believe there is a procedure for this

Answer (score 8):

```
cd /mydir_with_gz_files
for i in *gz
do
gzip -dkc < $i > /my_destination_dir/${i%%.gz}
done
```

This syntax is for extracting *multiple* `*.gz` files contained in `/mydir_with_gz_files` into a different directory.

1) Used `-k` option here because otherwise gzip will NOT preserve the archive itself. Good to remember!

2) I also want to emphasize what seems obvious to those giving the correct answer but wasn't so to me and the question's author: gzip will NOT extract files into a different DIRECTORY, but will expect that the resulting uncompressed file's NAME be specified as well.

This is achieved here by the `$i > ${i%%.gz}` *bash* [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) that strips a name like "`file.gz`" of its "`.gz`" suffix. With other shells the syntax will be different (if at all possible).

Answer (score 7):

In order to preserve the .tar file without GZIP compression,  I use a line like this with good results:

```
cat  file_to_uncompress.tar.gz | gzip -d > /destination_directory/packet_uncompressed.tar
```

That’s an useful and intuitive form to manage packets in some situations.